# Parameritized query C# SQL Injection protection

Tags: c#

I am filtering a gridview with a text box.

Can someone glance at the code and let me know if I am protected against SQL injection attacks?

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ItemNbr" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button_ItemNbr" runat="server" Text="ItemNbr Search" Font-Size="X-Small" OnClick="Button_ItemNbr_Click" />
<br /><br /><hr />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView_ItemNbr" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_ItemNbrGridView" Font-Size="X-Small" PageSize="125">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vendor Nbr" HeaderText="Vendor Nbr" SortExpression="Vendor Nbr" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vendor Name" HeaderText="Vendor Name" SortExpression="Vendor Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vendor Nbr Dept" HeaderText="Vendor Nbr Dept" SortExpression="Vendor Nbr Dept" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Item Status" HeaderText="Item Status" SortExpression="Item Status" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Item Nbr" HeaderText="Item Nbr" SortExpression="Item Nbr" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Item Desc 1" HeaderText="Item Desc 1" SortExpression="Item Desc 1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit Cost" HeaderText="Unit Cost" SortExpression="Unit Cost" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit Retail" HeaderText="Unit Retail" SortExpression="Unit Retail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Vendor Stk Nbr" HeaderText="Vendor Stk Nbr" SortExpression="Vendor Stk Nbr" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VNPK Qty" HeaderText="VNPK Qty" SortExpression="VNPK Qty" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VNPK Cost" HeaderText="VNPK Cost" SortExpression="VNPK Cost" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WHPK Qty" HeaderText="WHPK Qty" SortExpression="WHPK Qty" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WHPK Cost" HeaderText="WHPK Cost" SortExpression="WHPK Cost" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Group1" HeaderText="Group1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Group1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Group2" HeaderText="Group2" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Group2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Group3" HeaderText="Group3" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Group3" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_ItemNbrGridView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constring_RL_Name %>" SelectCommand="spRL_Prd_ItemMaster" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox_ItemNbr" DefaultValue="%" Name="ItemNbrSearch" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Microsoft security guidelines by using sql parameters you are protected from sql injection.

please check the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: Hazem - yes; but only if the parameter is used as part of a SQL statement - in this case the OP is using the parameter to pass a value into a Stored Procedure. It is possible to create a SQL Injection even using Parameters in this case. Depends what the stored procedure does.

Comment: Yes.. agree with you

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what your Stored Procedure does. Your spRL_Prd_ItemMaster procedure may construct dynamic SQL - just using parameters is a way of avoiding 'classic' SQL Injection attacks, but if the parameter is passed to a stored procedure then a SQL Injection attack can still be crafted if the procedure itself uses the parameter value to construct SQL.

Without seeing the text of spRL_Prd_ItemMaster it is not possible to categorically say that you are invulnerable to SQL Injection.